# How can I fetch all products from multiple categories (Woocommerce/Wordpress/React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce

I have managed to fetch products from the wordpress woocommerce API, from the endpoint `/wp-json/wc/store/products/`. The endpoint allows me to fetch only 9 products from the store. How can I fetch all products?

Comment: please describe your problem more presicely, show your api, explain what exactly you want to achieve? what is your code looks like right now?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just figured it out. Got the solution from the documentation - https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#list-all-products

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from the [woocommerce](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#list-all-products) documentation:

> **List all products**
>
> This API helps you to view all the products.
>
> **HTTP request**
>
> **`GET`** `GET /wp-json/wc/v3/products`

The API accepts a variety of parameters which are listed in the [docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#list-all-products).